# How to keep conversation data in MS Bot framework

Tags: save, botframework

I am working with Microsoft bot development framework, using its node.js sdk.
I have been looking for a way to save all the messages of a conversation. I set persistConversationData to true, and tried to access the conversationData using session.conversationData. However, it is empty.

1- Is there a builtin method to access all the messages within a conversation?

2- If persistConversationData is not for that, can anyone please explain its usage.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, messages will not be persisted by the Microsoft Bot Framework. For stateful operations, you can use the Bot State API the following ways:

- Set `userData`. The persisted data will be available to the same user across different conversations.
- Set `conversationData`. The persisted data will be available to all the users within the same conversation.
- Set `privateConversationData`. The persisted data will be available to the given user in the given conversation.
- Set `dialogData` for storing temporary information in between the steps of a waterfall.

According to the documentation, `conversationData` is disabled by default. If you want to use it, you have to set `persistConversationData` to `true`.

**tl;dr** You have to take care of persistence for yourself. E.g.

```
// ...

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, { persistConversationData: true });

bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    let messages = session.conversationData || [];
    messages.push(session.message);
    session.conversationData = messages;
});
```